# AngularJs sends an OPTION instead of a POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss

I've googlin' around about this issue. It seems that this is a normal behaviour, since I'm tryng to make a cross-site request. I have created my WebService based on everything I read round here:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Xml, UseHttpGet:=False)> _
Public Function Test() As String
    Me.Context.Response.Clear()
    Me.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    Me.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    Me.Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Return "<test>aRetStr</test>"
End Function
```

And this is a simple angularJS script:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])

myModule.controller('myController', function($scope, userRepository) {
    userRepository.getAllUsers().success(function(users) {
                                    alert("success");
                                    var myjson = JSON.parse(users);
                                    $scope.users = myjson})
                                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                    alert("error");
                                 });
    });

myModule.factory('userRepository', function($http) {
    return {
        getAllUsers: function() {
            $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
            var url = "http://localhost:2693/service.asmx/Test";
            var xml = $http.post(url, {test: 'test'});
            return xml;
        }
    };
});
```

The `X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *` and `text/plain` too are thinks suggested round here that doesn't worked in my case.
Really, Firebug show me an OPTIONS request, and no XSS error but a following POST never happens. The error `alert` is triggered and when that happens the config in the callback look like following:

```
Accept : application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type : application/json;charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest
method : POST
```

What can I do, why nothing happens?

Comment: what does `status` hold in the error callback?

Comment: `0`. And `null` in the `data`.

Comment: Have you tried adding _Access-Control-Allow-Methods_ with it set to the methods you are allowing? i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS`

Comment: Your web method doesn't expect a parameter, yet you are posting data. The service likely can't find a matching end point.

Comment: I've seen an answer to this somewhere online, but can't remember where. However, the solution was to add, on your webservice, an endpoint for an OPTION request on that URL.

Comment: dbugger and Patrick I've tried your tips but nothing changed.
@joao I will try to search something like that...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry the reply is not more complete, but I don't fully know your backend technology.

Basically, your Angular app is making a preflighted request to your server, because of CORS, meaning that first it is doing an HTTP.OPTIONS request on that URL and after a successful response from the server it will make the HTTP.xxx request (in this case a POST).

Because you haven't configured your webservice to respond to HTTP.OPTIONS and I believe that's what is causing your error.

The solution is to configure your webservice to reply to HTTP.OPTIONS requests with the following headers:

```
    response: 200, "ok"
    header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': http://yoursite.com
    header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, OPTIONS'
```

Please see more about the CORS specification here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests